# Program keeps showing "Unaligned address in store: 0x100100d2" error

Tags: mips, qtspim

I have to write a program that accepts a specific number of floats from the user and store them into an array.
However, whenever I try to store the float, QtSpim(MIPS Simulator) keeps saying "Unaligned address in store: 0x100100d2".
Is there something wrong with how I am trying to store $f0 into 0($s3)?

```
                        .data  
arrayLen:         .asciiz "Specify how many numbers should be stored in the array(at most 12): " 
enterNum:         .asciiz "Enter a number: " 
rawArray:         .asciiz "The array contains the following: " 
currArray:        .asciiz "The array currently contains the following: " 
resArray:         .asciiz "The result array contains the following: " 
blankLine:        .asciiz "\n"
floatArray:       .space 1000
                        .text
                        .globl    main    

main:
    la $a0, arrayLen    #load 'specify how many numbers' message 
    li $v0, 4           #print message
    syscall
    li $v0, 5           #read int (how many numbers) into v0
    syscall
    move $s0, $v0       #s0 holds the length of the array
    
    li $s1, 0           #s1 holds the index of the array
    la $s2, floatArray  #s2 holds the array
    
    Loop:
        slt $t1, $s1, $s0       #check if index(s1) is less than arrayLength(s0)
        beq $t1, $zero, Exit    #if not less than arrayLength exit program
        
        sll $t2, $s1, 2         #multiply index by 4 to get the Offset
        add $s3, $s2, $t2       #add offset to s2 to get floatArray[i](t3)
        
        
        
        la $a0, enterNum    #load 'enter a number' message 
        li $v0, 4           #print message
        syscall
        li $v0, 6           #read float (enter number) into f0
        syscall

        s.s $f0, 0($s3)   #store float into the array
        
        
        addi $s1, $s1, 1   #increment index
        
        j Loop            #jump back to start of loop
    
    Exit:
```

Comment: `s.s` (`swc1`) requires the address to be word-aligned. Your `floatArray` is not properly aligned.

Comment: How exactly would I word-align the address?

Comment: Check the manual to see if the simulator's assembler supports any `.align` directive. Otherwise, place `floatArray` first in the data section, before any of the strings.

Comment: Placing floatArray first in data section worked. Thank you Michael!